# How to get submenu item count and submenu name in barsubitem ribbon VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a winform with ribbon menu and i want to hide barbuttonitem in barsubitem on ribboncontrol.

The question is how can i get count on barsubitem? and how to get barbuttonitem name in barsubitem? and how to set visibility on barbuttonitem in barsubitem?

if possible i need this answer ASAP.

Tq

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BarSubItem.ItemLinks collection to access items and use the BarItemLink.Visible property to hide it. Like:

```
int count = barSubItem1.ItemLinks.Count;
BarItemLink itemLink = barSubItem1.ItemLinks.OfType<BarItemLink>().First(link => link.Item.Name == "your_name");
itemLink.Visible = false;
```